# Angular Reactive Forms - *ngFor errors rather than multiple 'if else' statements in html

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular4-forms

The only examples I can find for reactive forms validation error messages is outputting each forms label and each error message in a conditional in the HTML

```
<span *ngIf="form.controls['exampleelement'].hasError('required') && form.controls['exampleelement'].touched" class="login-error">You must include a element.</span>
<span *ngIf="form.controls['exampleelement'].hasError('minlength') && form.controls['exampleelement'].touched" class="login-error">Your element must be at least 20 characters .</span>
<span *ngIf="form.controls['exampleelement'].hasError('maxlength') && form.controls['exampleelement'].touched" class="login-error">Your element cannot exceed 20 characters .</span>
```

what I want to understand is a way to collect these error messages into an array and output them in real-time as they change etc like so

```
*ngFor="let error of errors"
```

Comment: Please see the updated answer, I had missed the check for `touched`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think doing this will make it easy for you. I have implemented what you asked, see if it helps you.

I have added these component variables:

```
formControlKeys = [];
errorMessages = {};
```

In the constructor:

```
// initalized the form and then..

this.formControlKeys = Object.keys(this.subscriptionForm.controls);

this.errorMessages = {
  required: "You must include a element.",
  max: "Max allowed value for input is 10",
  min: "Min allowed value for input is 4"
}
```

And added a class method:

```
getObjectKeys(arg) {
  return Object.keys(arg);
}
```

And then then in your template: (There are two loops, one to loop over all the form controls in the form and the other to loop over all the errors in eachControl)

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let eachControl of formControlKeys">
    <ng-container *ngIf="subscriptionForm.controls[eachControl].touched">
      <span *ngFor="let eachError of (getObjectKeys(subscriptionForm.controls[eachControl].errors))">
      {{errorMessages[eachError]}}<br>
      </span>
    </ng-container> 
 </ng-container>
```

See the working [**example here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-smh1td).

Comment: @Kravitz: Yeah I had seen that, the link was not opening, I had also updated the link, is it still not opening for you?